# object foreach loop iterate only even values

Tags: php

Basically I have a set of object values I want render in 2 separate html lists

I figure the simplest way to do this is by displaying evens only in one list, and odd only in the other

Here is the current code for displaying a single list

```
   <ul>
    <?php foreach ($values as $value) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $value->value; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014464/foreach-special-treatment-of-every-nth-item-odd-even-for-example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ul>

<?php 
/* read the index key */
foreach ($values as $key => $value) : 

 /* skip the current element if it doesn't have an even index */
 if($key % 2 == 1) continue; 

?>
<li><?php echo $value->value; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify if the array has integer index. So I use a separate index pivot. This will do.

```
$v=array();
$index = 1;
foreach ($values as $value){
   $v[($index++)%2][]=$value->value;
}
list ($evens, $odds) = $v;

echo "<ul><li>".implode("</li><li>", $odds)."</li></ul>"; // show list of odds
echo "<ul><li>".implode("</li><li>", $evens)."</li></ul>"; // shows list of even
```

Comment: yes there is an id for each value $value->id , would that make it simpler

Comment: @user1019144 it does not matter what is the name of the property of the objects. I was telling where `$values` is a normal array? or object or associative array?