# Insert/Close row after every 4 in foreach loop

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, foreach

I know this is supposed to be simple math but those two words do not exist in my vocab :)

I have a loop that runs a number of gallery images, Im using bootstrap so I have each item in the loop with a class of `col-md-3`, I simply need a way to add a new row and close the previous one after every fourth item.

I tried adding this when I echo out my closing and opening row but it didnt do the trick, maybe Im missing something, like basic math skills.  Here is what I tried: `$i % 4 === 0 && $i !== 0`

What I have almost does it, except the first item in the loop (0) is on a row all by itself, the others seem to be 4 to a row like I want.

The Code:

```
if ( $gallery_query->have_posts() ) :

                                $i = 0; //Count

                                //the loop
                                while($gallery_query->have_posts() ) : $gallery_query->the_post(); 

                                ?>

                                <article class="col-md-3 <?php echo $i; ?>" id="post-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" <?php  get_post_class(); ?> >
                                        <div class="masonry-thumbnail border">
                                            <a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" class="inner-shadow"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'masonry-thumb'); ?></a>
                                        </div><!--.masonry-thumbnail-->

                                    <div class="masonry-details">
                                        <h5><a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>"><span class="masonry-post-title"> <?php echo get_the_title(); ?></span></a></h5>
                                        <div class="masonry-post-excerpt">
                                            <?php echo getPostLikeLink(get_the_ID()); ?>  <p class="post-comment"><a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-comments qcomment" title="Comments"></i></a> <?php echo comments_number( ' ', '<sup>1</sup>', '<sup>%</sup>' ); ?></p><?php echo getBookmarkLink(get_the_ID()); ?>
                                        </div><!--.masonry-post-excerpt-->
                                    </div><!--/.masonry-entry-details -->  
                                </article><!--/.masonry-entry-->

                                <?php

                                    if($i % 4 === 0) {
                                        echo '</div><div class="row">';
                                    }

                                    ++$i;

                                endwhile;
```

Resources:
[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

[Similar questions/answers used to get this far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014464/foreach-special-treatment-of-every-nth-item-odd-even-for-example)

Answer (score 2):

Think about it: `0 mod 4` is still 0

You want to start your counter with 1

```
1 % 4 = 1
2 % 4 = 2
3 % 4 = 3
4 % 4 = 0 //Close and reopen a row!
```